# Training for Developers, QA and other R&D resources

Tags: training

Our organization plans to have a mandatory mass training program for all associates of R&D (around 1500 people) and we are currently evaluating trainers. The courses offered by vendors have very high UX content, like UXD life cycle, building personas, and storyboarding. We are not sure how such content adds value for folks who wont be moving to UX roles. We think, practically, the training has to be strategically phased out - starting with introduction to the basics, like terminology and benefits, then user needs, context of use, and understanding Heuristics, and the remaining subject as needed. Can you please suggest what you think is appropriate for this audience group?

The expected outcome from this training: Every resource to contribute to user experience within their job role limits. They are not expected to perform UX or UI Design tasks in their current roles.

Comment: What are you desired outcomes of this training?  Coming from an architectural background I would lock groups of people in a room and do design charrettes without technology.  Focus on identifying and abstracting the problems, then identifying goals and (previously)unseen opportunities.  Hopefully there will be some critical thought, risk taking, and hybrid design processes that arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think providing everyone with an overview is a great idea, it will help communication and when someone within the UX/UI team asks another person to do something they will know more about **why** they are being asked to do something.

It is also often the case that UX/UI/BA/Dev sometimes have blurred lines of responsibility, so it is good for everyone to know about UX as a whole.

I think the best way is to run a practical session, so the group can get a hands on and see the real tangible benefits of good UX.

If it was me I would look for a training provider who offers the following:

- Foundation to UX, what is it, where has it come from and why we use it
- How we carry out UX, potentially with the UCD process.
- Next I would run several practical sessions maybe using a real life scenario and show the UCD process in action.

If time is an issue, and it usually is! I would look at the following:

- Personas: Gives people an idea to why knowing about users is important.
- Information architect: How easy it is for people to get lost and how ambiguity can hinder.
- Prototyping: how quick and easy it is, especially lo-fi and the huge advantages it can bring,
- Iterative: How nothing is ever right first time, fail fast and fail often, and how that is okay and a good thing!

Hope this helps.